# Get count of child ul from a parent hidden ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to get the count of child uls from a parent ul which is display none. From the below html code, i want to get how many "child-div" are having the class "parent-div".

I have a html code like below.

```
<ul class="parent-div" style="diplay: none;">    
    <ul class="child-div">
        <li>
        ......
        ......
        </li>    
    </ul>    
    <ul class="child-div">
        <li>
        ......
        ......
        </li>    
    <ul>    
    <ul class="child-div">
        <li>
        ......
        ......
        </li>   
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I have tried the below jquery function, but i'm getting the result 0.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count   =   $('.parent-div > .child-div').length;
        alert(count);
     )};
</script>
```

Can any one please give me jquery solutions for the same.

Thanks,

VIGNESH KUMAR

Comment: var count = $(".parent-div").children().length;

Comment: Thanks Manish Goswamii. I have tried this code, but its showing me the result 0. Seems all tags are hidden.

Comment: `$('ul.parent-div > ul.child-div').length` - will give you direct child `ul`s

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.length` to get the number of children `ul` found on the parent.

Check your console.
https://jsfiddle.net/oL24k2Lt/2/

Comment: his HTML was worng. its written as `clas`. TYPO

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("ul.parent-div ul.child-div").length;
```

This will get all the ul element having class 'child-div' inside ul having class 'parent-div' and **.length** to count the result. 
See an working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/neeraj_webdev/8v71ja0p/1/